Is this form of password caching safe?
if user_info is None:
    return None

correct_password = user_info["pw_bcrypt"].encode()

if correct_password in state.cache.bcrypt:
    if password_to_check != state.cache.bcrypt[correct_password]:
        return None

else:
    if not bcrypt.checkpw(password_to_check, correct_password):
        return None

    state.cache.bcrypt[correct_password] = password_to_check

Worth noting that the input password is md5 encrypted, so there's no plaintext passwords stored in cache, and while I know md5 isn't great idea for password encryption, It's not depending on me, but the construction of osu client which sends md5 encrypted password to the server.
